# What is proper way to define connection string VB

Tags: vb.net, string, connection

My Visual Basic project uses this connecton string:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\IzolacCold V2\IzolacCold V2\izolac_cold_dbv2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

When I debug it, and go to debug folder, or when I "Release" it then problem occurs. If I run exe file program works normally but it save's data in database defined in connection string and not in database that is created in DEBUG folder (or RELESE folder).

How to properly connect to my databes. How to build proper connection string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [DataDirectory](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/where-is-datadirectory-) substitution string.

For example you could write your connectionstring as

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\izolac_cold_dbv2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

In your code then you could control the exact location of the DataDirectory executing this code, BEFORE any attempt to open a connection.

```
Dim commonDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
Dim myAppDataFolder = Path.Combine(commonDataFolder, "MyAppName")
if Not Directory.Exists(myAppDataFolder) Directory.CreateDirectory(myAppDataFolder)
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", myAppDataFolder)
```

(This example use the C:\programdata\myAppName folder because it is the most appropriate location for read/write data files needed by your application

Your deployment procedure should take care to create the above folder and place the database file in this location.

Comment: I belive that you just prevented mental brakedown :) THANK YOU !